# Count number of occurrences in a column

Tags: dax, powerbi

I ran a survey of members of different groups (e.g. Group 1 to 4) about whether they agree or disagree with something. I'm attempting to chart these responses in Microsoft PowerBI Desktop.

I have a data model loaded that includes columns like these in a single table:

```
Group    Question1   Question2
Group1   Agree       Agree
Group1   Disagree    Agree
Group4   Disagree    Disagree
Group3   Agree       Agree
Group2   Disagree    Agree
Group2   Agree       Disagree
Group4   Agree       Agree
Group1   Agree       Disagree
```

I'd like to know if there is a DAX that can count the number of occurrences of the words "Agree" and "Disagree" such that I can have those as values on a stacked bar chart (one chart per question):

```
Group1   Agree---------   Disagree----
Group2   Agree-------  Disagree-------
Group3   Agree----------  Disagree----
Group4   Agree------  Disagree--------
```

(apologies for the ASCII-art)

I've tried using the COUNTA() function but it just keeps returning the number of rows. I've also tried just dragging the question column in as a data field but it again, just makes each bar the same length as they all have the same number of total responses.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to unpivot your table - to have a structure like follows:

```
Group  |  Question  |  Answer
Group1 |  Question1 |  Agree
Group1 |  Question2 |  Disagree
...
```

Your measures then look like the following:

```
RowCount:= COUNTROWS(FactAnswer)

AgreeCount:=
CALCULATE(
    [RowCount]
    ,FactAnswer[Answer] = "Agree"
)

DisagreeCount:=
CALCULATE(
    [RowCount]
    ,FactAnswer[Answer] = "Disagree"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

We would need to create six measures (for clear and simplification)

1) `Agree Q1 = CALCULATE(COUNTA(SO_table[Question1]),SO_table[Question1]="Agree")`

2) `Agree Q2 = CALCULATE(COUNTA(SO_table[Question2]),SO_table[Question1]="Agree")`

3) `Disagree Q1 = CALCULATE(COUNTA(SO_table[Question1]),SO_table[Question1]="Disagree")`

4) `Disagree Q2 = CALCULATE(COUNTA(SO_table[Question2]),SO_table[Question1]="Disagree")`

5) `Total Agree = Agree Q1 + Agree Q2`

6) `Total Disagree = Disagree Q1 + Disagree Q2`

You can then use Stacked bar and plot `Total Agree` & `Total Disagree`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table per Question with the following DAX expression:

```
Table = SUMMARIZE('YourTable',YourTable[Group],"Agree",
COUNTAX(FILTER('YourTable',YourTable[Question1]="Agree"),
YuorTable[Question1]),"Disagree",
COUNTAX(FILTER('YourTable',YourTable[Question1]="Disagree"),YourTable[Question1]))
```

Example:

YourTable

[image]

For Question1 you will get the following table:

[image]

Once you have the table just create the chart you need.

Let me know if this was helpful.